# query getting record with special flag from two queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables as following .I need a result shown as below.

```
table1

id    name   
-----------------
1     john
2     raju
3     gopi
4     sarath

table2

userid     status
------------------
1          E
3          E


I need a query to select record from table like following

id    name      flag
---------------------
1     john      In
2     raju      Out
3     gopi      In
4     sarath    Out
```

If user having status 'E' will show in the result set as 'In' and others as 'Out'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple join and a case

```
SELECT table1.*, 
   CASE WHEN table2.status='E' THEN 'In' ELSE 'Out' END 
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.userid;
```

Answer (score 2):

i think below SQL will useful to you.

```
select table1.id, table1.name, CASE WHEN table2.status='E' THEN 'In' ELSE 'Out' END 
from table1 JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.userid;
```